# Running Macro in Power point. Setting it to run with a PS1 file, but getting error on application.run cmd

Tags: vba, powershell, powerpoint

Running Macro in Power point. Setting it to run with a PS1 file, but getting error on application.run cmd.

I am setting this up to create a bat file and task scheduler. The file opens but then I get an error upon running the script. Below is my script. Using Office 2016 professional. I have tried both just using the Macroname "mailme" and "Module1.mailme" Any help?

```
$ppt = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application 

#open file 
$FilePath = 'C:\Alerts.pptm' 
$workbook = $ppt.Presentations.Open($FilePath)  

#access the Application object and run a macro 
$app = $presentation.application 
$app.Run("Module1.mailme", @()) 
$ppt.Quit()    


       
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:10 char:1
+ $app.Run("Module1.mailme", @())
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: You've not set `$presentation` to anything...  You already have an Application reference in `$ppt` so try using that instead of `$app` ie `$ppt.Run("Module1.mailme", @())`

Comment: I now get:
type must not be ByRef
At line:9 char:1
+ $ppt.Run("Module1.mailme",@())
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: >> $ppt.Run("Module1.mailme")
>> $ppt.Quit()
Cannot find an overload for "Run" and the argument count: "1".
At line:9 char:1
+ $ppt.Run("Module1.mailme")

Comment: I'm not familiar with powershell so i don't know about `@()`   Does your macro expect arguments?

Comment: I got the code from : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-send-email-using-macro-in-powerpoint/b01552ba-4357-4ce9-aa20-0865e12c26bb Running the macro by itself is fine.

Comment: Have you tried `$ppt.Run("Module1.mailme")`

Comment: Yes I have. Same error codes.